How do I build IK rig for VR with multiple constraints?
I'm new to rigging and need some help understanding how to get this rig to work in the context of a VR game. I want to create this complex (IMO) rig that will rotate on different axis using IK. The goal is that in Unreal Engine using VR, you can grab that IK bone and move around the scene with it. I'll explain more in detail the constraints I need and then questions I still have on how to accomplish this.

I want:

Origin to rotate around Y axis (seems to be working)
Main Arm to rotate X axis with limited range. As in when you move the whole rig up and down, all motion up and down should happen on this bone only (seems to be working)
PointDown1 to well point down (this is where I'm starting to have issues)
Sideways1 to point sideways (this should rotate with pointdown1 always)
PointDown2 and Sideways2 are the same as PointDown1 and Sideways1 (creating two different lateral pivot points on the rig)
IK bone that I can have the player grab onto which allows me to properly move the entire rig in UE5

Questions about this:

What's the best method of knowing how to handle parent and child bones? I've seen different set ups where having the IK bone separate from rest of the bones works. Others have the IK bone as the parent to everything else. I still don't quite understand the outworkings of what that means.
In this setup, how do I get the PointDown bones to stay pointing down? Originally, I excluded them from the IK chain altogether but then I realized you don't have the rotation from the IK chain which is needed. I tried setting rotation constraint based on the IK bone itself but I couldn't find a solution that worked. Any ideas?
Since this is in VR, you can grab and walk away with the IK bone. Is there a way to limit the entire stretch of the rig so that in VR it can't move past its constraints? Is it considered bad to grab the IK bone and move it so that it detaches from the rig like this? Would I want to have that bone be stretchable so it never breaks from the rest of the rig?



If you need real time IK, or any other form of calculation made at play time, it should be built in the game engine using the game engine's tools.

Ah so I would just build up the rig and then I can put all constraints on it within UE5? I guess then the question is how do I know I've appropriately built up my rig? I would guess having it in it's current configuration would be enough? I've seen an example where for at head of PointDown you would have a bone to connect to tail of Sideways  to handle control.  Would this matter?

"...how do I know I've appropriately built up my rig?" If it works. How else?

Learn to build a shed before trying to build a house. Then you will need to do what you need to provide as a rig.  TBH i'm not even sure what you are looking for here is best answered with IK chains, which tend to become out of control beyond 2 or 3 bones. Other things exist, like spline IKs, or just splines, whatever. UE in particular might have other tools we don't even know that would do the job easier. But we're a Blender site here, it would be out of topic.
